# How to cast an object to a Type extracted at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, reflection

I am using reflection to get an object's type, or for this issue an object that has instance properties type, at runtime and then I need to change an existing variable's type into that newly found type. Is this possible? For example, the following code does *not* work in the line indicated within:

```vb
Public Sub DoSomething(x As T, y As T, exp As String)

'This is a instance property on the object of a different type
'i.e. 'T.AnotherType' We need to reflect to find out what type of object
'AnotherType is and work with it
If exp.Split(".").Count Then
  Dim tp As Type = Nothing
  tp = x.GetType
  tp = tp.GetProperty(exp.Split(".").ElementAt(0)).PropertyType()
  'Line below works, gets the right type, and now I need both x and y values passed in to be cast to this type.
  Dim typ As Type = tp.GetType
  'The line below WILL NOT work; can't cast to an unknown type at compile time - makes sense, but this is where I need a solution
  x = DirectCast(x, typ)
End If

End Sub
```

I also tried CTypeDynamic avialable in .NET 4.0 and *thought* I was on to something. The line of code below actually compiles but at runtime gives the following error below.

```
x = CTypeDynamic(x, tp.GetType())
```

***Conversion from type '[TypeOfT]' to type 'RuntimeType' is not valid.***

Note above, [TypeOfT] is not actually in the error message but the type of object passed into the method.

So is there anyway without Case Statements or a bunch of 'If TypeOf(...' statements that I can use the type I found at runtime and convert another object to its type dynamically?

Thanks! (**solution can be in VB.NET or C#** - thank you)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try [Convert.ChangeType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.changetype.aspx)

```vb
If exp.Split(".").Count Then
  Dim tp As Type = Nothing
  tp = x.GetType
  tp = tp.GetProperty(exp.Split(".").ElementAt(0)).PropertyType()
  'Line below works, gets the right type, and now I need both x and y values passed in to be cast to this type.
  Dim typ As Type = tp.GetType
  x = Convert.ChangeType(x, typ)
End If
```

Comment: Wasn't me I just checked this. Let me try it out!

Comment: I got the following exception: Object must implement IConvertible.

Comment: Yeah, that's a limitation you'd have to live with.  Otherwise, just always cast to Object.

Comment: Yeah I tried Object and got: "Overload resolution failed because no Public 'ChangeType' can be called without a narrowing conversion: Argument matching parameter 'conversionType' narrows from 'Object' to 'Type'.". The implementation code for IConvertible on the class is a bit much for how small of a need this is. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: I didn;t get it working as suggested but it is still a good suggestion. A similar question is elaborated on here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312858/how-can-i-convert-types-at-runtime

Comment: Even using C#, I managed to solve my problem with Convert.ChangeType. Something I forgot about.